# Uploading multiple files with single html file tag in struts 1.x

Tags: javascript, java, html, struts-1

I want to upload multiple files in struts 1.x. At my Jsp page it's only single html file tag.

I had old class which uses `com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest` .Here It uses request in its constructor and with single html file tag, it uploads multiple files successfully to server.

If I convert that class to struts1.x action class, I am not able to upload multiple files using form bean.

I tried through Java script,

In java script I can get all attached files as html file object. I tried creating other `<input type="file" ... />` through that html file object. But how can I assign file to `<input type="file".../>`

Comment: Could you please put your code with what you have tried ? It is hard to understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.